# LINKED LIST: Why do I need to "return;" in the if statement...even if i'm passing head by reference in the function(to add node at end)

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class node{
    public:
    int data;
    node* addr;.//it's address of the next node
    node(int val){
        data=val;
        addr = NULL;
    }
};

void addVal(node* &head, int val){

    node *n=new node(val);
    if (head==NULL){
        head = n;
        return;///<-WHY THIS?
    }
    node *p=head;
    while(p->addr!=NULL){
        p=p->addr;
    }
    p->addr=n;
    return;
}

void display(node *head){
    node *p=head;
    while(p!=NULL){
        cout<<p<<" "<<p->data<<" "<<p->addr<<endl;
        p=p->addr;
    }
}
int main(){
    node *head=NULL;
    addVal(head,1);
    addVal(head,2);
    addVal(head,3);
    addVal(head,4);
    addVal(head,5);
    display(head);
    return 0;
}
```

I was getting a blank terminal when I ran this without the return; inside of the if statement. Why is return necessary here? (I passed head's val by reference, so if I change it inside of the function the actual value would be affected as usual. But somehow it gets stuck without the return).

Comment: `return;` makes the function end immediately without running the rest of the function. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I'd recommend you run that code in your debugger and step through it line by line, then it should become clear to you what's exactly going on.

Comment: If you draw what happens using pen and paper, you would discover that adding the first node sets `head`'s `addr` pointer to point back to `head`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not `return` this is what happens:

```
node *p=head;                //   p equals head which equals n
while(p->addr!=NULL){        //   p->addr is NULL, this loop stops immediately
    p=p->addr;
}
p->addr=n;                   //   this assignes n to p's next ptr
return;
```

The use of many different names for the same thing can be a little confusing. You create a new node and the pointer to it is `n`. This is the new `head`. `p` also points to this new `head`.

Now `addr` is the next node of `head`.

If you do not return after creating the new `head` and assigning the pointer to `head` the function will continue to assing the pointer to the same node to `head->addr`. You'd get a list with a head that has itself as the next node.

You could have observed this by using a debugger.

Comment: To understand the problem completely: So as you said the head's next pointer has it's own address. So I wouldn't be able to add any more nodes. But the display function should atleast print the first one, but it doesn't because as soon as the next node is created- there's an infinite loop and the control never goes out of the function. 
When I tried adding just one value and display it...now there's and infinite loop in the display function.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @TheMerchant to understand the problem completely you should use a debugger to step though the code line by line and see exactly what happens